# How to handle multiple events in Rx (with dependencies)

Tags: wcf, events, silverlight-4.0, system.reactive

I have a few WCF calls, lets say A, B, C, D, E. They are in a SL application (so I guess I have to be careful with threading and such).
I want B to run after A has completed, while C can run concurrent with them. I want D to run after all three of them finished. And additionally based on a condition (simple if...) I want E to run too (concurrent with any of the above).

I just downloaded Rx and feel that it is the tool for this job. However I don't yet grasp all the operators and the tricks and such.

Can this be done? How? Please explain the operators required for this.

**EDIT** to add: For simplicity's sake let's say all of these services take a string (or an int) as a parameter, and returns something which implements a complex interface, so the events are simple EventHandlers (non-generic), and I cast them to their special interface in the handler code.
Some inputs are available at the start, some come from result of previous services (e.g. B's input string is computed based on A's result)

Comment: Can you provide signatures for the 5 WCF calls? Rx can do what you ask for, but without knowing the signatures it's a little hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity: edited the question to add the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the edit into account and put together a solution.

I do have to say that Microsoft has made it awfully hard to write simple WCF calls in Silverlight. Handling events to get the return data from async calls is just painful.

Having said that, with a little bit of "copy-and-paste" boiler-plate code, Rx does a great job of removing the complexity.

Here's what I came up with as the final client code:

```
        var service = new Service1Client();

        var abs =
            from a in service.AObservable("a")
            from b in service.BObservable(a)
            select new { a, b };

        var cs = service.CObservable("c");

        var abcs = abs.Zip(cs, (ab, c) => new { ab.a, ab.b, c });

        var ds =
            from abc in abcs
            from d in service.DObservable(abc.a, abc.b, abc.c)
            select String.Format(
                "A={0} B={1} C={2} D={3}",
                abc.a, abc.b, abc.c, d);

        var condition = true;

        var es = from e in condition
                    ? service.EObservable("e")
                    : Observable.Empty<string>()
                 select String.Format("E={0}", e);

        ds.Merge(es).ObserveOnDispatcher()
                    .Subscribe(r => this.label1.Content += " " + r);
```

On one hand this code isn't as pretty as I had hoped, but on the other I don't think I could get it any better. Hopefully you can see how your requirements are being met.

Now for the bad news - the extension methods must be created for every service proxy. The way the `EventArgs` are defined there is no way to get the results out without using the specific service reference class as the `this` parameter for the extension methods.

On the plus side though the code is mostly "copy-and-paste" with very little modification.

Also, you do need to create as many extension methods as many parameters you use plus one.

Here are the extension methods I needed to define for my sample code:

```
public static class Service1ClientEx
{
    public static Func<IObservable<R>> ToObservableFunc<EA, R>(this Service1Client service, Action<Service1Client> async, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> ah, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> rh, Func<EA, R> resultSelector)
        where EA : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
    {
        return () => Observable.Create<R>(o =>
        {
            var response =
                from ep in Observable.FromEventPattern<EA>(h => ah(service, h), h => rh(service, h))
                select resultSelector(ep.EventArgs);

            var subscription = response.Take(1).Subscribe(o);

            async(service);

            return subscription;
        }).ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    }

    public static Func<P0, IObservable<R>> ToObservableFunc<P0, EA, R>(this Service1Client service, Action<Service1Client, P0> async, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> ah, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> rh, Func<EA, R> resultSelector)
        where EA : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
    {
        return p0 => Observable.Create<R>(o =>
        {
            var response =
                from ep in Observable.FromEventPattern<EA>(h => ah(service, h), h => rh(service, h))
                select resultSelector(ep.EventArgs);

            var subscription = response.Take(1).Subscribe(o);

            async(service, p0);

            return subscription;
        }).ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    }

    public static Func<P0, P1, IObservable<R>> ToObservableFunc<P0, P1, EA, R>(this Service1Client service, Action<Service1Client, P0, P1> async, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> ah, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> rh, Func<EA, R> resultSelector)
        where EA : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
    {
        return (p0, p1) => Observable.Create<R>(o =>
        {
            var response =
                from ep in Observable.FromEventPattern<EA>(h => ah(service, h), h => rh(service, h))
                select resultSelector(ep.EventArgs);

            var subscription = response.Take(1).Subscribe(o);

            async(service, p0, p1);

            return subscription;
        }).ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    }

    public static Func<P0, P1, P2, IObservable<R>> ToObservableFunc<P0, P1, P2, EA, R>(this Service1Client service, Action<Service1Client, P0, P1, P2> async, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> ah, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> rh, Func<EA, R> resultSelector)
        where EA : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
    {
        return (p0, p1, p2) => Observable.Create<R>(o =>
        {
            var response =
                from ep in Observable.FromEventPattern<EA>(h => ah(service, h), h => rh(service, h))
                select resultSelector(ep.EventArgs);

            var subscription = response.Take(1).Subscribe(o);

            async(service, p0, p1, p2);

            return subscription;
        }).ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    }

    public static Func<P0, P1, P2, P3, IObservable<R>> ToObservableFunc<P0, P1, P2, P3, EA, R>(this Service1Client service, Action<Service1Client, P0, P1, P2, P3> async, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> ah, Action<Service1Client, EventHandler<EA>> rh, Func<EA, R> resultSelector)
        where EA : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
    {
        return (p0, p1, p2, p3) => Observable.Create<R>(o =>
        {
            var response =
                from ep in Observable.FromEventPattern<EA>(h => ah(service, h), h => rh(service, h))
                select resultSelector(ep.EventArgs);

            var subscription = response.Take(1).Subscribe(o);

            async(service, p0, p1, p2, p3);

            return subscription;
        }).ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    }

    public static IObservable<string> AObservable(this Service1Client service, string data)
    {
        return service
            .ToObservableFunc<string, ACompletedEventArgs, string>((s, p0) => s.AAsync(p0), (s, h) => s.ACompleted += h, (s, h) => s.ACompleted -= h, ea => ea.Result)
            .Invoke(data);
    }

    public static IObservable<string> BObservable(this Service1Client service, string data)
    {
        return service
            .ToObservableFunc<string, BCompletedEventArgs, string>((s, p0) => s.BAsync(p0), (s, h) => s.BCompleted += h, (s, h) => s.BCompleted -= h, ea => ea.Result)
            .Invoke(data);
    }

    public static IObservable<string> CObservable(this Service1Client service, string data)
    {
        return service
            .ToObservableFunc<string, CCompletedEventArgs, string>((s, p0) => s.CAsync(p0), (s, h) => s.CCompleted += h, (s, h) => s.CCompleted -= h, ea => ea.Result)
            .Invoke(data);
    }

    public static IObservable<string> DObservable(this Service1Client service, string dataA, string dataB, string dataC)
    {
        return service
            .ToObservableFunc<string, string, string, DCompletedEventArgs, string>((s, p0, p1, p2) => s.DAsync(p0, p1, p2), (s, h) => s.DCompleted += h, (s, h) => s.DCompleted -= h, ea => ea.Result)
            .Invoke(dataA, dataB, dataC);
    }

    public static IObservable<string> EObservable(this Service1Client service, string data)
    {
        return service
            .ToObservableFunc<string, ECompletedEventArgs, string>((s, p0) => s.EAsync(p0), (s, h) => s.ECompleted += h, (s, h) => s.ECompleted -= h, ea => ea.Result)
            .Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

Like I said, painful.

You certainly don't have to create these type of extension methods to use Rx with WCF in Silverlight, but it's my feeling that once you have created them then the client code becomes much, much easier to work with.

Let me know if you need more explanation on anything.

Comment: Before I even get to the extensions and whether I can automate/generalize anything... Can you explain Zip? Also when to use SelectMany (from+from) and when Merge?

Comment: @TDaver - `Zip` is like a zipper - it joins two observables matching values in pairs - {a, b, c}.Zip{1, 2, 3} -> {a1, b2, c3}. `SelectMany` is used essentially for chaining the results of one observable into the creation of a second one and then returning a flatten list of the results. Merge flattens `IO<IO<T>>` into `IO<T>`.

Comment: @TDaver: for a better understanding of some of the more important operators, check out the "In Depth" MSDN series. Most videos are only a couple of minutes long and cover things like Zip, SelectMany, etc. http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=%22Reactive+Extensions+API+in+depth%22&type=Blogs